# In Theme information , views-view.tpl.php (File not found, in folder ./)……?

Tags: views, theming

In Theme information

Display output : `views-view.tpl.php` (File not found, in folder ./)

Style output: `views-view-list.tpl.php` (File not found, in folder ./)

Row style output: `views-view-fields.tpl.php` (File not found, in folder ./)……

I know it's in conflict with devel_themer, but how to solve?